# cannot see "References" folder in Visual Studio 2019 "Solution Explorer"

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2019

I cannot see the "References" folder in the "Solution Explorer" pane of Visual Studio 2019. When I right click on the project name (C#), and point to "Add", I only see "New File", "Add New item", and "New Folder". How can I show "References" folder? My goal's to add a dll through the "References" folder.

Comment: Are you right clicking on the solution or the project folder?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing? I can think of a couple explanations for this (some pretty unlikely, but worth clarifying).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason you are only getting those three options is because you are in `Folder View`. You can switch your view from Folder View to Solution View which will give you the menu you are looking for to add the Reference to a Project.

[image: Change Folder View / Solution View]